# Laravel - Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::create()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm still getting this error, even though I have added the service provider and alias in config/app.php

**Controller.php**

```
    public function export_app_csv(){
        $data = Item::get()->toArray();
        return Excel::create('test_export', function($excel) use ($data) {
                $excel->sheet('mySheet', function($sheet) use ($data)
                {
                    $sheet->fromArray($data);
                });
         })->download('xlsx');
    }
```

**config/app.php**

```
    /*
     * Package Service Providers...
     */
    Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class,

    /* aliases */
    'Excel' => Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class,
```

the method in the controller is just an example from a site. because I still dont have any idea how laravel excel works.

Then following the [docs](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/docs/3.0/export/basics#docs) gave me more problems.

```
namespace App\Exports;

class InvoicesExport implements FromCollection
{
    public function collection()
    {
        return Invoice::all();
    }
}
```

the above code gives me `Interface 'App\FromCollection' not found`

Comment: this is not the way to ask for help here, show us what you have done so far. That includes how you did it.

Comment: Can you please give us some more information regarding it post your code and error line

Comment: Please check the edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work if you followed the documentation correctly.

```
public function get_export_csv(){
    $allData = $this->data->get();

    $module = $this->module;

    Excel::create('projects', function($excel) use ($allData, $module) {

        $excel->sheet('sheet1', function($sheet) use ($allData, $module) {
            $sheet->loadView('admin.'.$this->module.'.excel', compact('allData','module'));
        });
    })->download('csv');

}
```

In your blade you only need this table

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>First Name</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php $count = 0; ?>
    @foreach($allData as $row)
        <?php $count++; ?>
        <tr>
            <td>{{$count}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->first_name}}</td>

        </tr>
    @endforeach
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i prefer to use loadView() because its faster than fromArray()... if you want learn how fromArray() works check this link https://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/exporting-laravel-data-to-an-excel-spreadsheet/

Comment: i got error like this when using Excel::create()

Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::create()

my composer.json

 "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
 "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.17"

any clue?